# "External component has thrown an exception" on rebuild

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, components, external

I'm really hitting a wall over here.

I was making some changes to an existing web site project in VS2010 and everything was fine.

Sudently, i was unable to rebuild the solution. I can build and run it, with every change i made working. When i try to publish it, it gives the error "External component has thrown an exception" and gives no aditional information.

So, i started everything from zero and started to rebuild the solution after each change, to check where the problem was. The error is thrown when i add a new control (be it a text box) and then, in the code behind i try to set is value to something (like Me.TextBox1 = ""), although the textBox is correctly recognized.

Has someone experienced anything similar? I'm googling for 3 days and i just can't solve this really important issue.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

- I tried to delete all references and re-add them but nothing.
- Other apps are working fine.
- Is there any way that i can debug this error? i tried to check the events log, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem.

The textboxes were inside a panel and for the new ones i had to declare a textbox and assign it to PanelName.FindControl(TextBoxName).

The already existent ones didn't need this.

Still don't know why it was working fine and suddently stopped working.